# выбор столбцов по заданным параметрам pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

Имеется следующий датафрейм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо его преобразовать в следующий вид:

```
Регистрационный номер   Год    Наименование           Значение
   1140280002235        2013  Нематериальные активы     0
   1140280002235        2013  Основные средства         0
   1140280002235        2014  Нематериальные активы     0
   1140280002235        2014  Основные средства         0
   1140280002235        2015  Нематериальные активы     0
   1140280002235        2015  Основные средства         825 000
   ..........................................................
   1147746032752        2015  Основные средства        2 314 000
```

В принципе можно установить Регистрационный номер и год как индексы (set_index).
Не понимаю логику как преобразовать исходный датафрейм таким образом, чтобы потом легко можно было фильтровать по годам и рег.номеру.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import re
    df_findata = pd.read_csv(open('spark_fin_data.csv', 'r', encoding='KOI8-R'), sep = ',', decimal=',')
    df_findata.head()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS [Временная ссылка на данные](https://yadi.sk/d/6A8_B_xwo6209w)

Comment: Можете привести небольшой воспроизводимый пример входного и выходного DataFrame'ов в текстовом/CSV виде или в виде Python кода?

Comment: ссылка на csv файл https://yadi.sk/d/6A8_B_xwo6209w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\data.csv', dtype={'Регистрационный номер':'str'})

cols2drop = [
  '?',
 'Наименование',
 'Адрес (место нахождения)',
 'Дата регистрации',
 'Возраст компании',
 'Дата ликвидации',
 'Статус',
 'Вид деятельности/отрасль',
 'Организационно-правовая форма',
 'Форма собственности']

df = (df.drop(cols2drop, axis=1)
        .set_index('Регистрационный номер')
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .rename(columns={'level_1':'name',0:'val'}))

df[['Год','Наименование']] = \
    (df.pop('name')
       .str.extract(r'(\d{4}),\s*([^,]*?)\s*,'))


df['Значение'] = pd.to_numeric(df.pop('val').str.replace('\s*',''), 
                               errors='coerce')
df = df.reset_index()
```

Результат:

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
        Регистрационный номер   Год                         Наименование  Значение
0               1140280002235  2015                    Основные средства    825000
1               1140280002235  2015                  Внеоборотные активы    825000
2               1140280002235  2016                  Внеоборотные активы     37000
3               1140280002235  2017                  Внеоборотные активы      6000
4               1140280002235  2015                               Запасы     58000
5               1140280002235  2016                               Запасы    162000
6               1140280002235  2017                               Запасы      2000
...                       ...   ...                                  ...       ...
1137143         1088602002004  2016  Прибыль (убыток) до налогообложения   6980000
1137144         1088602002004  2017  Прибыль (убыток) до налогообложения  -2941000
1137145         1088602002004  2013              Чистая прибыль (убыток)  33468000
1137146         1088602002004  2014              Чистая прибыль (убыток)  28719000
1137147         1088602002004  2015              Чистая прибыль (убыток)   1887000
1137148         1088602002004  2016              Чистая прибыль (убыток)   4821000
1137149         1088602002004  2017              Чистая прибыль (убыток)  -3229000

[1137150 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Pavel, всегда рад помочь :)